# How do I ensure an array gets sorted in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, sorting, express

I am trying to do something like this with very large arrays (5k+):

```
    exports.sortedArray = function(req,res){

    var fs = require("fs");
    var path = 'somePath.txt';

    //async
    fs.readFile(path, function(err,f){
        var incoming = f.toString();
        //var returner = csvarray(incoming);
        var returner = incoming.split("\n");
        for (var i=0;i<returner.length;i++){
            returner[i] = returner[i].split(",");
        }
        returner.sort(function(a,b){
            return b[3]-a[3];
        });

        res.json(returner);
    })
}
```

The file gets read.  The csv string is converted to an array.  But the function returns the array before sorting it.

The code above is the ajax response from a server running node.js and express.  I have the same problem if I sort the array on the other end of the Ajax call, i.e. 'console.log(result);' in the browser instead of 'res.json' on the server. The printed array is still unsorted.

I've tried several hacky solutions.  If I stall the return (such as with setTimeout), I get the sorted array.  But I'd rather have the results when ready, such as with a callback.  I just can't figure out how to attach a callback to a sort function.  I feel like I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: Can you show us what `csvarray` does?

Comment: Looks like csvarray is an async function. Try passing the .sort and res.json function to the csvarray callback.

Comment: `sort()` is synchronous, so there's no way the array is not sorted, and if `csvarray()` was async, you wouldn't have an array. Are you sure express doesn't mess things up, as calling `res.json` explicitly converts the array to JSON and could be changing the order somehow?

Comment: adeneo is right. The code would fail hard if `csvarray` was async.

Comment: csvarray simply returns an array from a csv file synchronously.  The array is returned, so there shouldn't be issues at that point.  I also understood sort() to be synchronous, hence my confusion.  As adeneo suggests, I suspect res.json might be the culprit.

Comment: Is it possible `b[3]-a[3]` produces `NaN` for any inputs. That can mess up your sorting

Comment: @megawac That's possible. But would it mess up the entire sort?  I'll test it.

Comment: @Nicks for sure consider `[9,1,NaN, "a", 88, 33].sort(function(a,b) {return a-b}); //=>[1, 9, NaN, "a", 33, 88]`

Comment: @megawac But that would still sort something,  whereas my code does not sort at all.  (unless I stall the res.json)

Comment: I cant help you without seeing a sample of `incoming` string

Comment: @megawac Never mind.  That solved the problem.

Comment: @megawac I'd vote you up, but I lack the privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.sort` may behave oddly when you return a non-comparable item such as `NaN`. One common way to ensure you don't return NaN in sorts like yours is to check if `a` and `b` are finite

I would suggest you rewrite your sort similar to:

```
returner.sort(function(a,b){
    var aFinite = isFinite(a[3]), bFinite = isFinite(b[3]);
    if(!aFinite || !bFinite) {
       if(bFinite) return 1;
       if(aFinite) return -1;
       return 0;//both not finite
    }
    return b[3]-a[3];
});
```

I think this should work too

```
returner.sort(function(a,b){
    var aFinite = isFinite(a[3]), bFinite = isFinite(b[3]);
    return aFinite && bFinite ? b[3]-a[3] : aFinite-bFinite;//noting that a true - false = 1, false - true = -1 etc
});
```